# one js script for several IDs or buttons

Tags: javascript, button

I am trying to add 2 or more buttons to activate a video with only one Script/js code, but the second button just does not work.

The idea is not to stack or overload my page with a lot of scripts that are basically identical. I know this is level 1 super basic but I can't find the answer in internet.

Here is my code:

```js
  var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');// Get the modal
  var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");// Get the button that opens the modal
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
  btn.onclick = function() {modal.style.display = "block";}// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
  span.onclick = function() {modal.style.display = "none";}// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
  window.onclick = function(event) {if (event.target == modal) {modal.style.display = "none";}}// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
```

```css
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    /* background dark */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px;
    box-shadow: 0 11px 11px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4),0 16px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #515c70;
    color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 12px 16px;} /* video frame */

.modal-footer {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #515c70;
    color: white;


#myVideo {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;


}
```

```html
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>My Web Page</title>
</head>

<div id="my_buttons">

 <button id="myBtn" class="button" >Boton 1</button>
 <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div style="width:60%" class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
         <span class="close">&times;</span>
         <h2>Modal Header</h2>
      </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
   <video autoplay muted loop weight=100% width=100%>
    <source src="video_code/A.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
   <p>Some other text...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
        <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
     </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <button id="myBtn" class="button" >Boton 2</button>
 <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div style="width:60%" class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
         <span class="close">&times;</span>
         <h2>Modal Header</h2>
      </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
   <video autoplay muted loop weight=100% width=100%>
    <source src="video_code/A.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
   <p>Some other text...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
        <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
     </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<div>
```

Comment: HTML ids need to be unique within the page there fore you can't have 2 buttons with the same id. Change them to classes instead.

Comment: Thank you! did not work will keep trying

Comment: What your js code is doing?

Comment: @Brian if it still not working after changing all the `id` to `class` then share your js code as well

Comment: Thanks guys I edited the post and add the code as an image! its very simple I am a 5 day newbe and just whant to understand the terrain. hope you guys can help

Comment: OK! I have added the complete code! as you can see only button 1 works! what do I need to do to use only one .js and add as may videos as I want without having to add a .js with different ID for every single one I add? there must be a clean solution to this

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to give your button a class and a data attribute to specify the target which it will trigger.

Something similar to this:

```
<button class="js-toggle" data-target="#modal-1">Button 1</button>
<button class="js-toggle" data-target="#modal-2">Button 2</button>

<div id="modal-1">Modal 1</div>
<div id="modal-2">Modal 2</div>

<script>
$('.js-toggle').on('click', function() {
  var target = $(this).data('target');
  $(target).toggleClass('is-active');
});
</script>
```